# Determining neighbours of cell two dimensional list

Tags: python, matrix

I have a list of lists, something like

`[[1, 2, 3,],[4, 5, 6,],[7, 8, 9]]`.

Represented graphically as:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I'm looking for an elegant approach to check the value of neighbours of a cell, horizontally, vertically and diagonally. For instance, the neighbours of [0][2] are [0][1], [1][1] and [1][2] or the numbers 2, 5, 6.

Now I realise, I could just do a bruteforce attack checking every value a la:

```
[i-1][j]
[i][j-1]
[i-1][j-1]
[i+1][j]
[i][j+1]
[i+1][j+1]
[i+1][j-1]
[i-1][j+1]
```

But thats easy, and I figured I can learn more by seeing some more elegant approaches.

Comment: Do you want to get the indices or the values? And do you want a function that can do random access on every index or a function that returns a list of (val, neighbors_of_val) pairs? -- Just getting the indices is too simple for a elegant solution, but what you really want to do might be more interesting

Comment: Either or - I deliberately left this question fairly general so people wouldn't feel constrained.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
# Size of "board"
X = 10
Y = 10

neighbors = lambda x, y : [(x2, y2) for x2 in range(x-1, x+2)
                               for y2 in range(y-1, y+2)
                               if (-1 < x <= X and
                                   -1 < y <= Y and
                                   (x != x2 or y != y2) and
                                   (0 <= x2 <= X) and
                                   (0 <= y2 <= Y))]

>>> print(neighbors(5, 5))
[(4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 4), (5, 6), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

I don't know if this is considered clean, but this one-liner gives you all neighbors by iterating over them and discarding any edge cases.

Comment: What if the "board" is `10201x10201`?

Comment: @CF84: Then the constants `X` and `Y` would need to have different values assigned to them. Do you have an issue regarding this—what's your point?

Comment: @CDspace how does the edit deviate from the original intent of the post? If you mean the one-liner, it can still be written on one line with a normal function. Also, it hasn't been a one-liner anyway since the previous edit. At least the uppercase X and Y variables should be changed, since they are hard to spot.

Comment: Why doesn't `print(neighbors(10, 9))`  return empty set, when I am giving a value out of range?

Comment: I think the conditions are wrong. they should be (-1 < x <X) and (-1 < y < Y) and 0 <= x2 <X) and  (0 <= y2 < Y). Note omitting = in front of array size X and Y.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you have a square matrix:

```
from itertools import product

size = 3

def neighbours(cell):
    for c in product(*(range(n-1, n+2) for n in cell)):
        if c != cell and all(0 <= n < size for n in c):
            yield c
```

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and thanks to Python's [yield expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) and [star operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), the function is pretty [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) but still readable enough.

Given a matrix size of 3, you can then (if needed) collect the neighbours in a `list`:

```
>>> list(neighbours((2,2)))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

What the function does can be visualized as follows:

[image: Function visualization]

Comment: hi, this looks great. But what about an matrix with unequal row and col numbers, like 2*4 array?

Comment: @Xue having the matrix width and height as a tuple, e.g. `size = [3, 4]` you can check whether `c[0]` and `c[1]` are larger than (or equal to) zero and smaller than `size[0]` and `size[1]` respectively. E.g. `0 <= i < bound for i, bound in zip(c, size)`.

Answer (score 12):

mb...

```
from itertools import product, starmap

x, y = (8, 13)
cells = starmap(lambda a,b: (x+a, y+b), product((0,-1,+1), (0,-1,+1)))

// [(8, 12), (8, 14), (7, 13), (7, 12), (7, 14), (9, 13), (9, 12), (9, 14)]
print(list(cells)[1:])
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer, and I ran it along with the question's example in Python 2.7.

Comment: How would you add a check to make sure the coordinates don't exceed the bounds of the matrix?

Answer (score 7):

```
for x_ in range(max(0,x-1),min(height,x+2)):
  for y_ in range(max(0,y-1),min(width,y+2)):
    if (x,y)==(x_,y_): continue
    # do stuff with the neighbours

>>> a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> width=height=3
>>> x,y=0,2
>>> for x_ in range(max(0,x-1),min(height,x+2)):
...   for y_ in range(max(0,y-1),min(width,y+2)):
...     if (x,y)==(x_,y_): continue
...     print a[x_][y_]
... 
2
5
6
```

Answer (score 5):

If someone is curious about alternative way to pick direct (non-diagonal) neighbors, here you go:

```
neighbors = [(x+a[0], y+a[1]) for a in 
                    [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)] 
                    if ( (0 <= x+a[0] < w) and (0 <= y+a[1] < h))]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no cleaner way to do this. If you really want you could create a function:

```
def top(matrix, x, y):
     try:
         return matrix[x][y - 1];
     except IndexError:
         return None
```

Comment: @ Kaizer.se: Thanks, wasn't sure which one it was and too lazy to look it up or try it.

Comment: +1 this is not a complete solution, but interesting since that could be quite a Pythonic way to search for neighbors -- it's EAFP

Comment: This actually won't work. I was doing a similar solution and realized this. Negative indexes actually used for looking up the index in reverse order. For example  -1 means the last element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your list:

```
(x - 1, y - 1) (x, y - 1) (x + 1, y - 1)
(x - 1, y)     (x, y)     (x + 1, y)
(x - 1, y + 1) (x, y + 1) (x + 1, y + 1)
```

So the horizontal neighbors of (x, y) are (x +/- 1, y).

The vertical neighbors are (x, y +/- 1).

Diagonal neighbors are (x +/- 1, y +/- 1).

These rules apply for an infinite matrix.
To make sure the neighbors fit into a finite matrix, if the initial (x, y) is at the edge, just apply one more restriction to the coordinates of neighbors - the matrix size.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def sl(lst, i, j):
    il, iu = max(0, i-1), min(len(lst)-1, i+1)
    jl, ju = max(0, j-1), min(len(lst[0])-1, j+1)
    return (il, iu), (jl, ju)

>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> tup = 0, 2
>>> [lst[i][j] for i, j in itertools.product(*sl(lst, *tup)) if (i, j) != tup]
[2, 5, 6]
```

I don't know how elegant it seems to you, but it seems to work w/o any hard-coding.

Answer (score 0):

This generates all indices:

```
def neighboring( array ):
    nn,mm = len(array), len(array[0])
    offset = (0,-1,1) # 0 first so the current cell is the first in the gen
    indices = ( (i,j) for i in range(nn) for j in range(mm) )
    for i,j in indices:
        all_neigh =  ( (i+x,j+y) for x in offset for y in offset )
        valid = ( (i,j) for i,j in all_neigh if (0<=i<nn) and (0<=j<mm) ) # -1 is a valid index in normal lists, but not here so throw it out
        yield valid.next(), valid ## first is the current cell, next are the neightbors

for (x,y), neigh in neighboring( l ):
    print l[x][y], [l[x][y] for x,y in neigh]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [@JS_is_bad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145256/js-is-bad) for a great hint about the neighbors. Here is the running code for this problem:

```
    def findNeighbours(l,elem):
    #This try is for escaping from unbound error that happens 
    #when we try to iterate through indices that are not in array
    try:
        #Iterate through each item of multidimensional array using enumerate
        for row,i in enumerate(l):
            try:
                #Identifying the column index of the givem element
                column=i.index(elem)
            except ValueError:
                continue
            x,y=row,column
    
    #    hn=list(((x,y+1),(x,y-1))) #horizontal neighbours=(x,y+/-1)
    #    vn=list(((x+1,y),(x-1,y))) #vertical neighbours=(x+/-1,y)
    #    dn=list(((x+1,y+1),(x-1,y-1),(x+1,y-1),(x-1,y+1))) #diagonal neighbours=(x+/-1,y+/-1)
        #Creating a list with values that are actual neighbors for the extracted index of array
        neighbours=[(x,y+1),(x,y-1),(x+1,y),(x-1,y),(x+1,y+1),(x-1,y-1),(x+1,y-1),(x-1,y+1)]
        #Creating a universe of indices from given array
        index_list=[(i,j) for i in range(len(l)) for j in range(len(l[i]))]
        #Looping through index_list and nested loop for neighbours but filter for matched ones
        # and extract the value of respective index
        return_values=[l[index[0]][index[1]] for index in index_list for neighbour in neighbours if index==neighbour]
        return return_values,neighbours
    except UnboundLocalError:
        return []
```

Answer (score 0):

If lambdas daunt you here you are .But lambdas make your code look clean.@johniek_comp has a very clean solution TBH

```
k,l=(2,3)
x = (0,-1,+1)
y = (0,-1,+1)
cell_u = ((k+a,l+b) for a in x for b in y)
print(list(cell_u))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by one of the previous answers.

You can use min() and max() functions to shorten the calculations:

```
width = 3
height = 3

[(x2, y2) for x2 in range(max(0, x-1), min(width, x+2)) 
                    for y2 in range(max(0, y-1), min(height, y+2))
                    if (x2, y2) != (x, y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by johniek's answer here is my solution which also checks for boundaries.

```
def get_neighbours(node, grid_map):
   row_index, col_index = node
   height, width = len(grid_map), len(grid_map[0])
   cells = list(starmap(lambda a, b: (row_index + a, col_index + b), product((0, -1, +1), (0, -1, +1))))
   cells.pop(0) #  do not include original node
   cells = list(filter(lambda cell: cell[0] in range(height) and cell[1] in range(width), cells))
   return cells
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def numCells(grid):
    x=len(grid)
    y=len(grid[0])
    c=0
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            value_=grid[i][j]
            f=1
            for i2 in range(max(0,i-1),min(x,i+2)):
                for j2 in range(max(0,j-1),min(y,j+2)):
                    if (i2,j2) != (i,j) and value_<=grid[i2][j2]:
                        flag=0
                        break
                if flag ==0:
                    break
                else:
                    c+=1
    return c
```

Comment: This determines the number of neighbours, if I understand it correctly, which isn't what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNeighbors(matrix: list, point: tuple):
    neighbors = [] 
    m = len(matrix)
    n = len(matrix[0])
    x, y = point 
    for i in range (x -1, x +2): #prev row to next row
        for j in range(y - 1, y +2): #prev column to next col 
            if (0 <= i < m) and (0 <= j < n): 
                neighbors.append((i,j))
    return neighbors
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get the neighbour elements

from itertools import product
def neighbours(arr, *coordinate):
    x, y=coordinate[0], coordinate[1]
    row=[i for i in range(x-1,x+2) if 0<=i<len(arr)]
    col=[i for i in range(y-1,y+2) if 0<=i<len(arr[0])]
    neighbours= set(product(row,col))-{(x,y)}
    return [arr[val[0]][val[1]] for val in neighbours]


# Example:

arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

# 1 2 3
# 4 5 6
# 7 8 9

print(neighbours(arr,0,0))
print(neighbours(arr,0,1))
print(neighbours(arr,1,1))

# Output

[2, 4, 5]
[6, 1, 5, 3, 4]
[2, 6, 8, 1, 7, 3, 9, 4]

arr2=[[12,34,12,54],[23,23,11,44],[76,67,87,22],[13,78,45,22],[55,77,33,87]]

# 12 34 12 54
# 23 23 11 44
# 76 67 87 22
# 13 78 45 22
# 55 77 33 87

print(neighbours(arr2,0,0))
print(neighbours(arr2,2,2))
print(neighbours(arr2,4,3))

# Output

[34, 23, 23]
[11, 67, 78, 23, 22, 22, 45, 44]
[45, 22, 33]
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

maybe you are checking a sudoku box. If the box is n x n and current cell is (x,y) start checking:

```
startingRow = x / n * n;
startingCol = y/ n * n
```