# Best way not to run out of list index

Tags: python

Let's say I have 2D list and I want to do a check if previous/next element equals something. What is the best way to make sure that I will not access `list[-1][-1]` or `list[len + 1][len + 1]`?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
if list[y + 1][x] == value and list[y - 1][x] == value:
    do something
elif list[y][x + 1] == value and list[y][x - 1] == value:
    do something else
... # end so on
```

I can't see any other options except for doing:

```
if y - 1 > 0 and y + 1 < len(list) and x - 1 > 0 and x + 1 < len(list[y]):
```

Which doesn't seem right...

Comment: Well, you're "other option" would look better if you wrote it like this: `if 0 < y < len(list) - 1 and 0 < x < len(list[0]) - 1:`

Comment: @pyrate no offense, but something seems off about having to iterate through the indices of a list (2D or not) in Python. I get the sense there's an overall better way that we just can't know without knowing the problem better.

Comment: @kojiro - I agree that this doesn't look like a good solution, something just smells wrong here.

Comment: @kojiro: I disagree. It looks like he's working with a coordinate system (it's tagged pygame- it could be, for example, a character moving around a room, or pieces moving on a board).

Comment: @DavidRobinson Either we'll know, or we'll never know. :)

Comment: @kojiro I agree that it's maybe not a best way to check for neighbors. I am trying to output tile depending on surrounding neighbors.

Comment: @kojiro: Would you agree that when one is working with an XY coordinate system, it's reasonable to use indices? (Now that pyrate's mentioned tiles it seems clear!)

Comment: @pyrate [You mean like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620940/determining-neighbours-of-cell-two-dimensional-list)

Comment: @DavidRobinson and you are absolutely right, it's a game, every tile has a bunch of variations like {'ns': (0, 1)} - "tile connected with same tiles from north and south will use image with coordinates 0, 1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common way to solve this is to add some "padding" around your grid that contains a sentinel value that indicates you are off the grid (such as `0` or `-1` or `None` or something). Your valid indexes, instead of being from `0` to `size-1`, would be from `1` to `size` (with a list length of `size+2`).

Comment: Hah, don't change the way you handle data, change the data itself... Thank you, it's a great way of thinking