# Switch operands in loops Python 3

Tags: python, operands

I want to be able to switch operands each time through a loop. So the first time through I'd like to add column. The second time through the loop I'd like to subtract from column. The third time through I would like to subtract from column and subtract from row. The fourth time through I'd like to subtract from column and add to row. Is this possible to write one loop to accomplish this instead of several? Thanks for the help!

```
#add            
for x in range(1,8): 
    if game[column+x][row] == 'W':
        game[column+x][row] = 'B'
    elif game[column+x][row] == 'B':
        return      
#subtract       
for x in range(1,8): 
    if game[column-x][row] == 'W':
        game[column-x][row] = 'B'
    elif game[column-x][row] == 'B':
        return
#etc....
for x in range(1,8): 
    if game[column-x][row-x] == 'W':
        game[column-x][row-x] = 'B'
    elif game[column-x][row-x] == 'B':
        return

for x in range(1,8): 
    if game[column-x][row+x] == 'W':
        game[column-x][row+x] = 'B'
    elif game[column-x][row+x] == 'B':
        return
```

Comment: What operand is changing? There seem to be inconsistencies in your code. Specifically, you are using `game[column+x]` the first time, but `game[column-x]` the other three times.

Comment: You show three apparent operand changes here; please clarify the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: just updated the question. Hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: Are you trying to cover an 8x8 grid?

Comment: yep an 8x8 grid

Comment: Sorry, 17x17, not 8x8. Also, is `game` a 2D list?

Comment: Also, are you trying to check the entire grid or and flip everything, or just the first `W`?

Comment: BTW, add @MadPhyicist somewhere in your response so I get a notice.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620940/determining-neighbours-of-cell-two-dimensional-list

Comment: Could you describe your goals in detail? And what exactly is the code supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a list of operands and iterated through the list.That worked

Answer (score 1):

By your code I'm assuming you want to mark each 'W' surrounding cell with 'B'. This should be enough:

```
neighbours = [
  (-1, -1),
  (-1,  0),
  (-1,  1),
  ( 0, -1),
  ( 0,  0),
  ( 0,  1),
  ( 1, -1),
  ( 1,  0),
  ( 1,  1)
  ]

game = [
  ['W', 'W', 'E'],
  ['' ,  '',  ''],
  ['' ,  '',  '']
]

print game

row, col = 1, 1 # center of the game's table

for x, y in neighbours:
   if game[row + x][col + y] == 'W':
      game[row + x][col + y] = 'B'

print game
```

Comment: `for x, y in neighbors:`

Comment: @MadPhysicist indeed! Updated.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think that doesn't make a difference. The number of neighbours of any given position in the `game` table are always the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this actually doesn't solve the problem. I actually want to be able to change the operands (+,-) so that I can go up to 8. I don't know if it possible.