# Most efficient way to check cells and change neighbors matching a condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, neighbours

I'm using a pandas dataframe to store a dynamic 2D game map for a rougelike style game map editor. The player can draw and erase rooms. I need to draw walls around these changing rooms.

I have this:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  .  .  .  x  .  .
1  .  .  x  x  .  .
2  .  x  x  x  .  .
3  .  .  .  .  .  .
4  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

And need this:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  .  #  #  x  #  .  
1  #  #  x  x  #  . 
2  #  x  x  x  #  . 
3  #  #  #  #  #  . 
4  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

**What is the most efficient way to do this?**

So far I followed the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621118), but this leaves me with some nested `if` and `for` before and after the `lambda`. As I have to check first if a cell is currently dug out. Then check all eight neighbors if they are dug out or not before changing the matching cells. This really takes a tool on the frame rate. I can't be the first to struggle with something like this, but got stuck at finding a solution.

I was hoping to find a way by applying `mask` or a similar binary comparison. Still, I have no idea how to efficiently do the neighbor checks without falling back into nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called a binary dilation. You can do this on the underlying numpy array with [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html):

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation
import numpy as np

a = df.eq('x').to_numpy()
# [[False False  True  True  True False]
#  [False  True  True  True  True False]
#  [ True  True  True  True  True False]
#  [False  True  True  True False False]
#  [False False False False False False]]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(binary_dilation(a), 'x', df))
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  .  .  x  x  x  .
1  .  x  x  x  x  .
2  x  x  x  x  x  .
3  .  x  x  x  .  .
4  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Now to get a different symbol, you can use a more complex mask (`binary_dilation(a)^a`) with a XOR operation (`^`):

```
a = df.eq('x').to_numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(binary_dilation(a)^a, '#', df))
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  .  .  #  x  #  .
1  .  #  x  x  #  .
2  #  x  x  x  #  .
3  .  #  #  #  .  .
4  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

###### all neighbors

Use a different structuring element (here a 3x3 matrix of 1s):

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

a = df.eq('x').to_numpy()
kernel = np.ones((3,3))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(binary_dilation(a, kernel)^a, '#', df))
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  .  #  #  x  #  .
1  #  #  x  x  #  .
2  #  x  x  x  #  .
3  #  #  #  #  #  .
4  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

###### other kernels

You can easily adapt the code to have any combination of neighbors

example: top left

```
kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]])

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  .  #  #  x  .  .
1  #  #  x  x  .  .
2  #  x  x  x  .  .
3  .  .  .  .  .  .
4  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a step forward. But I need all eight neighbors. This solution only gives me six. Any way to also catch the edges like 0,1 or 3,0 etc.?

Comment: @JackBox I hadn't seen. Yes of course, just use a different kind of structuring element ;) I'll update the answer

Comment: @JackBox note that you could do the same with pandas only using many `shift` operations, but this would be much less efficient/flexible ;)